# How to decode JSON returning an Array in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Here is the api response which i want to show in my app but i'm unable to do so maybe some decoding issue but i could not fix this its throwing alot of errors !

```
[
  {
    "domains": [
        "marywood.edu"
    ],
    "alpha_two_code": "US",
    "country": "United States",
    "web_pages": [
        "http://www.marywood.edu"
    ],
    "name": "Marywood University",
    "state-province": null
},
{
    "domains": [
        "lindenwood.edu"
    ],
    "alpha_two_code": "US",
    "country": "United States",
    "web_pages": [
        "http://www.lindenwood.edu/"
    ],
    "name": "Lindenwood University",
    "state-province": null
  }
]
```

How to decode this json ?

Here is my code. I tried searching across the web but there are a lot of JSON formats so i was unable to do it .A little help would be appreciated

```
  Future<Api> fetchData() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
      'http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?country=United+States'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Api.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to Load Data');
  }
}

class Api {
  final List<String> domains;
  final String code;
  final String country;
  final List<String> pages;
  final String name;
  final String? state;

  const Api({
    required this.domains,
    required this.code,
    required this.country,
    required this.pages,
    required this.name,
    required this.state,
  });

  factory Api.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Api(
      domains: json['domains'] as List<String>,
      code: json['alpha_two_code'] as String,
      country: json['country'] as String,
      pages: json['web_pages'] as List<String>,
      name: json['name'] as String,
      state: (json['state-province'] != null)
          ? json['state-province'] as String
          : "",
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run over the response and parse the individual entries

```
Iterable it = json.decode(response.body);

List<Api> apis = List<Api>.from(it.map((model)=> Api.fromJson(model)));
```